# "New" route being ignored in ember-app-kit

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-app-kit

My application keeps generating the default route even though I have the route explicitly defined. I think I'm overlooking a naming convention but googling, stackoverflowing, discuss.emberjs.com'ing and plain old cursing at the computer isn't getting me anywhere yet.

app/router.js

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();    

Router.map(function(){                 
  this.resource('things', function() {
    this.route('new');                 
  });                                  
});                                    

export default Router;
```

app/routes/things_new.js

```
var ThingsNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({     
  model: function() {                       
    window.console.log('hello hello');      
    return this.store.createRecord('thing');
  }                                         
});                                         

export default ThingsNewRoute;
```

Visiting `http://localhost:8000/#/things/new` the template renders well and there are no errors. The output from ember's logging:

```
generated -> route:application Object {fullName: "route:application"} ember.js:415
generated -> route:things Object {fullName: "route:things"} ember.js:415
generated -> route:things.new Object {fullName: "route:things.new"} ember.js:415
generated -> controller:application Object {fullName: "controller:application"} ember.js:415
Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember267> Object {fullName: "view:application"} ember.js:415
generated -> controller:things Object {fullName: "controller:things"} ember.js:415
Rendering things with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember283> Object {fullName: "view:things"} ember.js:415
generated -> controller:things.new Object {fullName: "controller:things.new"} ember.js:415
Rendering things.new with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember293> Object {fullName: "view:things.new"} ember.js:415
Transitioned into 'things.new' ember.js:415
Ember Debugger Active
```

The problem is this:

```
generated -> route:things.new Object {fullName: "route:things.new"} ember.js:415
```

It shouldn't generate this because I'm defining it. Is there some file naming convention that I'm not following?

Also looking at Ember Inspector in Chrome. Under "Own Properties" under ThingsNewRoute:

```
routeName: things.newSend
controller: (generated things.new controller)
lastRenderedTemplate: things.new
teardownOutletViews: [ function() { ... } ]
```

Comment: which build tool are you using for your project?

Comment: @chrmod, he is using ember-app-kit

Comment: [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ember-app-kit to get your routes picked up correctly by the resolver you have to put them in sub directories.

For example, for your use case by having a router map like:

```
Router.map(function(){                 
  this.resource('things', function() {
    this.route('new');                 
  });                                  
});
```

The directory structure should be:

```
app/
   ...
   routes/
      things/
        new.js
        ...
```

Because the resolver expects the route `ThingsNewRoute` to be found in `app/routes/things/new.js`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried this earlier and (thought) it didn't work. Tried it again after seeing your answer and, of course, it's all peachy now lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `ThingsNewRoute` should be a property of your application object. So the declaration would look like:

```
App.ThingsNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    ....
})
```

Replace name `App` with a variable to which you assigned your `Ember.Application.create();`

Comment: Per the comments under the question, I'm using ember-app-kit.